# how to use if in matlab for 2 matrix condition?

Tags: matlab

i have 2 reflection coefficient equations R1 and R2 from K with condition absolute must below 1, i use if command for this situation .But when i plot the graph the absolute reflection coefficient still above 1. (K is matrix with 1 column and 201 row)

```
R1=K+sqrt(K.^2-1);
R2=K-sqrt(K.^2-1);
 if abs(R1)<1
    r=R1;
 else
    r=R2; 
 end
```

[this is the K in excel](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mTXwE6AZ5GppWppz3Ji6aSBmPYg17-ie)

```
real    imaginer
-0.7536 0.0512
-0.802  0.0426
-0.8496 0.0408
-0.8872 0.0327
-0.927  0.0338
-0.9575 0.0242
-0.979  0.0174
-0.9977 0.0113
-10,031 0.0029
-10,012 -0.007
-0.9876 -0.0167
-0.9654 -0.0249
-0.9299 -0.0401
-0.8797 -0.0488
-0.8176 -0.0623
-0.7297 -0.0782
-0.6458 -0.0865
-0.5351 -0.1051
-0.4098 -0.1197
-0.2701 -0.1349
-0.1177 -0.1489
0.0536  -0.1699
0.213   -0.1853
0.3933  -0.1921
0.5519  -0.1857
0.7128  -0.1896
0.8511  -0.1712
0.9468  -0.1452
10,222  -0.0943
10,375  -0.04
10,134  0.0365
0.9361  0.1255
0.8122  0.2168
0.6622  0.3108
0.4657  0.3774
0.2577  0.4497
0.0431  0.4775
-0.1463 0.5093
-0.3442 0.4999
-0.5203 0.4782
-0.6692 0.4417
-0.7781 0.3822
-0.8856 0.3293
-0.9703 0.2615
-10,187 0.193
-10,524 0.1254
-10,614 0.0557
-10,539 -0.0016
-10,297 -0.0698
-0.9879 -0.1212
-0.9355 -0.1829
-0.8721 -0.2298
-0.8011 -0.2783
-0.7232 -0.325
-0.6401 -0.3586
-0.5455 -0.4008
-0.4429 -0.43
-0.3524 -0.4433
-0.2455 -0.4769
-0.1336 -0.4863
-0.0391 -0.5073
0.0779  -0.5105
0.1776  -0.5196
0.2869  -0.5152
0.3893  -0.5084
0.4831  -0.4978
0.5888  -0.4907
0.6822  -0.4574
0.7614  -0.4381
0.8484  -0.4017
0.9098  -0.3585
0.9771  -0.3172
10,268  -0.2607
10,667  -0.2102
10,969  -0.1464
11,115  -0.0724
11,141  -0.0019
10,981  0.0838
10,645  0.1546
10,135  0.2457
0.9409  0.3332
0.8657  0.4061
0.7519  0.4973
0.6426  0.5635
0.5072  0.6302
0.3633  0.6782
0.2148  0.7161
0.0382  0.7573
-0.1051 0.7395
-0.273  0.7359
-0.4273 0.7154
-0.5653 0.6794
-0.6971 0.6279
-0.8202 0.555
-0.905  0.493
-0.9996 0.4155
-10,716 0.3239
-11,006 0.2549
-11,444 0.1479
-11,464 0.0722
-11,493 -0.0031
-11,282 -0.0814
-11,040 -0.1603
-10,645 -0.2219
-10,187 -0.2787
-0.9514 -0.3223
-0.8878 -0.3841
-0.8225 -0.42
-0.7415 -0.4606
-0.6607 -0.4889
-0.5577 -0.5319
-0.482  -0.5512
-0.3775 -0.5614
-0.2918 -0.5798
-0.1621 -0.5712
-0.0979 -0.5917
0.0149  -0.5559
0.1062  -0.5734
0.2142  -0.5648
0.3159  -0.5363
0.3844  -0.5302
0.5019  -0.5066
0.5805  -0.4709
0.6626  -0.4506
0.7482  -0.4117
0.8005  -0.363
0.8799  -0.3378
0.9349  -0.2889
0.9883  -0.2449
10,306  -0.1946
10,643  -0.1373
10,870  -0.1025
10,935  -0.0389
10,840  0.0184
10,732  0.0639
10,333  0.1274
0.9906  0.1739
0.9243  0.2293
0.8455  0.2752
0.7527  0.3035
0.6292  0.3394
0.5384  0.3524
0.3808  0.3845
0.2509  0.4067
0.0931  0.4004
-0.0423 0.3839
-0.2123 0.377
-0.3666 0.3537
-0.4838 0.3309
-0.6157 0.288
-0.7211 0.2604
-0.8322 0.2172
-0.8947 0.1791
-0.9618 0.1366
-10,024 0.0932
-10,299 0.0493
-10,415 0.0099
-10,333 -0.0243
-10,092 -0.0612
-0.9798 -0.0906
-0.9321 -0.1302
-0.8796 -0.1472
-0.8121 -0.17
-0.7414 -0.1886
-0.6649 -0.2019
-0.5907 -0.2149
-0.4793 -0.2271
-0.4011 -0.2224
-0.3121 -0.2408
-0.1948 -0.2343
-0.0997 -0.2322
0.008   -0.2328
0.1304  -0.2224
0.2662  -0.2213
0.4093  -0.2298
0.553   -0.2406
0.7094  -0.3018
0.8613  -0.383
0.9745  -0.5634
0.9796  -0.8226
0.7781  -0.9412
0.6424  -0.8495
0.6264  -0.8147
0.6071  -0.6706
0.6682  -0.6029
0.6759  -0.5596
0.71    -0.5218
0.7479  -0.4825
0.7691  -0.4476
0.8264  -0.4056
0.8412  -0.3912
0.8511  -0.3813
0.8689  -0.3425
0.899   -0.3375
0.8827  -0.3198
0.9024  -0.3164
0.929   -0.2876
0.9106  -0.2855
0.9695  -0.2079
10,342  -0.5353
0.8692  -0.5046
```

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including data to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Trenton_M im sorry, i just edited now and include the K in excel

Comment: @Trenton_M No, it should NOT be a link. All the data should be within the post without any reliance on external links. Screenshots are also not acceptablee

Comment: sorry sir i am newbee at here so i cant understand what are you are talking about hehe

Comment: @Trenton_M The OP says that `K` is a matrix with 1 column and 201 row. This is easily pastable in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure exactly what you are asking, but I believe the problem you are experiencing is that r is above 1?

K is an imaginary number, where the first column is the real part and the second column is the imaginary part, do I have that correctly? So the first K value is -0.7536+0.0512i, right?

Ok, so did you perhaps intend to cycle through each position of the R1 matrix and see if each one was less than 1. Because right now what you are doing is saying if any values in the entire R1 vector are less than 1, then r equals to the entire R2 vector.

If you want to go through each position in the vector, you should do this:

```
R1=K+sqrt(K.^2-1);
R2=K-sqrt(K.^2-1);
l=length(R1);
for p=1:l
 if abs(R1(p))<1
  r(p)=R1(p);
 else
  r(p)=R2(p); 
 end
end
```